# Azure Data Factory: How to pass triggered blob container name to the invoked Function Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've configured a trigger on blob container change which should invoke a Function activity(HTTP POST), and I want to use this container name in the function itself(trigger container could be changed frequently, and I don't want to change function code). How can I pass it?

I found only an example for the copy activity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger) you posted in your question,you could pass the value of `folder path` and `file name` to pipeline as parameters. `@triggerBody().folderPath` and `@triggerBody().fileName` could be configured in the parameters of pipeline.

[image]

For example:

[image]

Then if you want to get the container name ,you just need to split the folder path with `/` so that you could get the root path which is container name exactly.

Comment: This is what I try to explain in a question. I know how to use it in a copy activity but didn't find a way to use it in a function activity

Comment: lets say the folder path returned is Data/Data_Import/DEV/IE . How can I just strip/trim this to get the Business unit 'IE' ? This will then be passed on as a parameter through the rest of the other pipelines in the ADF